# Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme')

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-manifest, voip

![give me error : ( ]

i tryed every thing ...

> [2014-11-15 17:56:06 - LoginActivity]
>   C:\Users\Different\workspace\LoginActivity\AndroidManifest.xml:15:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme'). [2014-11-15 17:56:06 -
>   LoginActivity]  [2014-11-15 17:56:07 - LoginActivity]
>   C:\Users\Different\workspace\LoginActivity\AndroidManifest.xml:15:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme'). [2014-11-15 17:56:07 -
>   LoginActivity]  [2014-11-15 17:56:10 - LoginActivity]
>   C:\Users\Different\workspace\LoginActivity\AndroidManifest.xml:15:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme'). [2014-11-15 17:56:10 -
>   LoginActivity]  [2014-11-15 17:56:12 - LoginActivity]
>   C:\Users\Different\workspace\LoginActivity\AndroidManifest.xml:15:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
>   'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme'). [2014-11-15 17:56:12 -
>   LoginActivity]  im using eclipse "windows 7"

the error is in this line `android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >`

in androidmanifest.xml
, this is the whole code `

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
    android:required="false"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="Log In">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CallActivity"
        android:label="Make a Call"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
</application>
```

`

Comment: post your styles.xml

Comment: <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>

Comment: Since your theme is named **AppBaseTheme**, `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` should be `android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There it is.

Either change:

```
style name="AppBaseTheme"
```

to

```
style name="AppTheme"
```

in your *styles.xml* file. Or change:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

to

```
android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
```

in your manifest application tag.

Both should be the same. Basically, your app is trying to use AppBaseTheme which doesn't exist.

Comment: hello Hirak Chhatbar ,it's worked with no error , but when i run the program give me error message" unfortunately,com.sinch.apptoappcall has stopped"

Comment: plz post your error logcat. there must be somthing wrong with your code.

Comment: i can't upload whole file because it's too long , i uploaded the last http://textuploader.com/on5j

Comment: not this one... only the part that comes in red color when ur app crashes

Comment: ur error is an activiy not found exception for some LoginActivity class. There are 2 possible reasons for that :  u mught not have defined that activity in android manifest file or there may be some error in onCreate method of that activity... does ur app has any LoginActivity class?

Comment: I just restart my Android Studio, error is fixed :D