# Unity, Google Play Games, CommandInvokationFailure

Tags: java, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

i open my project and see this error. 
I did not change anything in the project, only switched the platform with android on windows, did the assembly and returned it and then there was an error. I have already reinstalled the anroid_sdk and google play games in the project. Switch target platform, delete manifest - not fix problem too. 
What to do?

> CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
>   D:\Android_SDK\build-tools\28.0.2\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay
>   -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "D:/Android_SDK\platforms\android-27\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_
>   --extra-packages android.support.compat:android.support.coreui:android.support.coreutils:android.support.fragment:android.support.mediacompat:android.support.v4:com.google.android.gms.auth.api:com.google.android.gms.auth.api:com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.license:com.google.android.gms.auth:com.google.android.gms.auth.license:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms.base.license:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.common.license:com.google.android.gms.drive:com.google.android.gms.drive.license:com.google.android.gms.games:com.google.android.gms.games.license:com.google.android.gms.nearby:com.google.android.gms.nearby.license:com.google.android.gms.tasks:com.google.android.gms.tasks.license:com.google.games.bridge:com.google.example.games.mainlibproj:com.mnp.popups:com.unity.udp.sdk:com.unity.udp.udpsandbox:com.unity3d.ads:com.unity.channel.sdk.editor.xiaomi:com.unity.udp.sdk.common
>   -S "C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-compat-25.2.0\res"
>   -S "C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-core-ui-25.2.0\res"
>   -S "C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-core-utils-25.2.0\res"
>   -S "C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-fragment-25.2.0\res"
>   -S "C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-media-compat-25.2.0\res"
>   -S "C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-v4-25.2.0\res"
>   -S "C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-auth-11.6.2\res"
>   -S "C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-auth-api-phone-11.6.2\res"
>   -S "C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-auth-base-11.6.2\res"
>   -S "C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res"
>   -S "C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-basement-11.6.2\res"
>   -S "C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-drive-11.6.2\res"
>   -S "C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-games-11.6.2\res"
>   -S "C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-nearby-11.6.2\res"
>   -S "C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-tasks-11.6.2\res"
>   -S "C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.games.gpgs-plugin-support-0.9.50\res"
>   -S "C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\mobile-native-popups\res" -S
>   "C:\Unity\The
>   Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\udpsandbox\res" -S
>   "C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\unity-ads\res"
>   -S "C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\UnityChannel\res" -S
>   "C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\utils\res"
>
> stderr[ AndroidManifest.xml:38: error: Error: No resource found that
>   matches the given name (at 'theme' with value
>   '@style/VrActivityTheme').
>
> ] stdout[ Configurations:  (default)
>
> Files:   values\values.xml
>       Src: () C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\utils\res\values\values.xml 
>   AndroidManifest.xml
>       Src: () AndroidManifest.xml
>
> Resource Dirs:   Type values
>       values\values.xml
>         Src: () C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\utils\res\values\values.xml
>   Including resources from package:
>   D:\Android_SDK\platforms\android-27\android.jar applyFileOverlay for
>   drawable trying overlaySet Key=ic_launcher.png trying overlaySet
>   Key=mio_btn_bg.png trying overlaySet Key=mio_btn_bg_click.png trying
>   overlaySet Key=mio_btn_change_account_nor.png trying overlaySet
>   Key=mio_btn_change_account_sel.png trying overlaySet
>   Key=mio_icon_login_wait.png trying overlaySet Key=mio_img_title.png
>   trying overlaySet Key=mio_list_item_single_bg_60_n.9.png trying
>   overlaySet Key=mio_list_item_single_bg_60_p.9.png trying overlaySet
>   Key=mio_mipay_payment_alipay.png trying overlaySet
>   Key=mio_mipay_payment_arrow.png trying overlaySet
>   Key=mio_mipay_payment_wx.png trying overlaySet
>   Key=mio_pad_bg_float_win.png trying overlaySet
>   Key=mio_selector_mipayment_item.xml trying overlaySet
>   Key=unity_white_logo.png trying overlaySet Key=ic_launcher.png
>   baseFile 0 has flavor xhdpi-v4 overlayFile 0 has flavor mdpi-v4
>   overlayFile 1 has flavor hdpi-v4 overlayFile 2 has flavor xhdpi-v4
>   nothing matches overlay file ic_launcher.png, for flavor mdpi-v4
>   nothing matches overlay file ic_launcher.png, for flavor hdpi-v4 found
>   a match (2) for overlay file ic_launcher.png, for flavor xhdpi-v4
>   trying overlaySet Key=ic_launcher.png baseFile 0 has flavor mdpi-v4
>   baseFile 1 has flavor hdpi-v4 baseFile 2 has flavor xhdpi-v4
>   overlayFile 0 has flavor nodpi-v4 nothing matches overlay file
>   ic_launcher.png, for flavor nodpi-v4 trying overlaySet
>   Key=common_full_open_on_phone.png trying overlaySet
>   Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml trying overlaySet
>   Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.xml trying overlaySet
>   Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.xml trying overlaySet
>   Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png trying
>   overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_disabled.xml trying
>   overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light.xml trying
>   overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.xml trying
>   overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.xml trying
>   overlaySet
>   Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png trying
>   overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml trying
>   overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused.xml trying
>   overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.xml trying
>   overlaySet
>   Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png trying
>   overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_disabled.xml trying
>   overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml trying
>   overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused.xml trying
>   overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.xml trying
>   overlaySet
>   Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background.9.png trying
>   overlaySet Key=googleg_disabled_color_18.png trying overlaySet
>   Key=googleg_standard_color_18.png trying overlaySet
>   Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.xml baseFile 0 has
>   flavor  overlayFile 0 has flavor watch-v20 nothing matches overlay
>   file common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.xml, for flavor
>   watch-v20 trying overlaySet
>   Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_disabled.xml baseFile 0 has flavor 
>   overlayFile 0 has flavor watch-v20 nothing matches overlay file
>   common_google_signin_btn_text_disabled.xml, for flavor watch-v20
>   trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.xml
>   baseFile 0 has flavor  overlayFile 0 has flavor watch-v20 nothing
>   matches overlay file common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.xml,
>   for flavor watch-v20 trying overlaySet Key=app_icon.png trying
>   overlaySet Key=app_icon_round.png applyFileOverlay for layout trying
>   overlaySet Key=mio_activity_paylist.xml trying overlaySet
>   Key=mio_item_pay.xml trying overlaySet Key=udp_login_activity.xml
>   applyFileOverlay for anim applyFileOverlay for animator
>   applyFileOverlay for interpolator applyFileOverlay for transition
>   applyFileOverlay for xml applyFileOverlay for raw applyFileOverlay for
>   color trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
>   trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml trying
>   overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_tint.xml applyFileOverlay for
>   menu applyFileOverlay for font applyFileOverlay for mipmap Processing
>   image: res\drawable-ldpi\app_icon.png Processing image:
>   res\drawable-mdpi\app_icon.png Processing image:
>   res\drawable-hdpi\app_icon.png Processing image:
>   res\drawable-xhdpi\app_icon.png
>       (processed image res\drawable-ldpi\app_icon.png: 98% size of source) Processing image: res\drawable-xxhdpi\app_icon.png
>       (processed image res\drawable-mdpi\app_icon.png: 99% size of source) Processing image: res\drawable-xxxhdpi\app_icon.png
>       (processed image res\drawable-hdpi\app_icon.png: 97% size of source) Processing image: res\drawable-ldpi\app_icon_round.png
>       (processed image res\drawable-ldpi\app_icon_round.png: 98% size of source) Processing image: res\drawable-mdpi\app_icon_round.png
>       (processed image res\drawable-mdpi\app_icon_round.png: 99% size of source) Processing image: res\drawable-hdpi\app_icon_round.png
>       (processed image res\drawable-xhdpi\app_icon.png: 98% size of source) Processing image: res\drawable-xhdpi\app_icon_round.png
>       (processed image res\drawable-hdpi\app_icon_round.png: 97% size of source) Processing image: res\drawable-xxhdpi\app_icon_round.png
>       (processed image res\drawable-xhdpi\app_icon_round.png: 98% size of source) Processing image: res\drawable-xxxhdpi\app_icon_round.png
>       (processed image res\drawable-xxhdpi\app_icon.png: 97% size of source) Processing image: C:\Unity\The
>   Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_full_open_on_phone.png
>       (processed image C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_full_open_on_phone.png:
>   120% size of source) Processing image: C:\Unity\The
>   Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_full_open_on_phone.png
>       (processed image C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_full_open_on_phone.png:
>   105% size of source) Processing image: C:\Unity\The
>   Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png
>       (processed image C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png:
>   157% size of source) Processing image: C:\Unity\The
>   Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png
>       (processed image C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png:
>   132% size of source) Processing image: C:\Unity\The
>   Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png
>       (processed image C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png:
>   126% size of source) Processing image: C:\Unity\The
>   Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png
>       (processed image C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal_background.9.png: 121% size of source) Processing image: C:\Unity\The
>   Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png
>       (processed image C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png:
>   171% size of source) Processing image: C:\Unity\The
>   Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png
>       (processed image C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png:
>   136% size of source) Processing image: C:\Unity\The
>   Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png
>       (processed image C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png: 133% size of source) Processing image: C:\Unity\The
>   Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png
>       (processed image C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png:
>   124% size of source) Processing image: C:\Unity\The
>   Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png
>       (processed image C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png:
>   135% size of source) Processing image: C:\Unity\The
>   Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png
>       (processed image res\drawable-xxhdpi\app_icon_round.png: 97% size of source) Processing image: C:\Unity\The
>   Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png
>       (processed image C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png:
>   119% size of source) Processing image: C:\Unity\The
>   Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png
>       (processed image C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png:
>   117% size of source) Processing image: C:\Unity\The
>   Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background.9.png
>       (processed image C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background.9.png:
>   147% size of source) Processing image: C:\Unity\The
>   Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background.9.png
>       (processed image C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal_background.9.png:
>   126% size of source)
>       (processed image C:\Unity\The Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.android.gms.play-services-base-11.6.2\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png: 117% size of source) Processing image: C:\Unity\The
>   Rabbit\Temp\StagingArea\android-l

Comment: There is a more complete error in your editor.log file that should tell you exactly what the problem is. I'd go look for that. Search for `stderr`

Comment: @RetiredNinja i add full log, pls check it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947246/error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-theme-with-value-st)